# Parse log file for value changes

Tags: text-processing, logs

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31535/9760) I have reduced a log file to this:

```
Timestamp:1359021601 2013-01-17 15:00:01
size: 10G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
Timestamp:1359025201 2013-01-17 16:00:01
size: 11G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
...snip hundreds of lines...
Timestamp:1359021601 2013-01-24 10:00:01
size: 11G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
Timestamp:1359025201 2013-01-24 11:00:01
size: 11G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
Timestamp:1359028801 2013-01-24 12:00:01
size: 11G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
Timestamp:1359032401 2013-01-24 13:00:01
size: 12G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
```

That pattern will carry on for hundreds of lines. I would like to reduce the file to only show the Timestamps and sizes when the size changes, like this:

```
Timestamp:1359021601 2013-01-17 15:00:01
size: 10G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
Timestamp:1359025201 2013-01-17 16:00:01
size: 11G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
Timestamp:1359032401 2013-01-24 13:00:01
size: 12G   /mnt/SolrFiles/solr/api/
```

Can this be accomplished using common Linux CLI tools such as grep and sed?

Comment: What about using a few lines of Perl or Python to get this solved?

Comment: I'm open to all solutions, but ideally I would be able to add the solution as a bash alias without installing anything to `$HOME/bin`. Even better would be a one-liner that I could bang out from memory and impress my colleagues with! I'll be using this from a few terminals SSHed into a few different servers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a typical job for `awk`:

```
awk '/^Timestamp/{t=$0; next}
     /^size/ && $2 != last_size {
        print t
        print
        last_size = $2
     }'
```

If you want to make it obscure and consise, you could do:

```
awk '!(/^T/&&t=$0)&&$2!=l&&(l=$2)&&$0=t RS$0'
```

Comment: Cool! I would have done it using Perl, but this is definitely better.

Comment: Thanks, Stephane! Is there any way to concise this into a single line of bash? If not then no worry.

Comment: @dotancohen you can put the above awk on a single line, but leaving the newlines in won't prevent you from running it in an interactive shell.

Comment: When I put it in an alias or shell script, I get this error: `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near !=
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near`. For instance: `alias grow="cat hourly.log | sed -n '/Timestamp/{p;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p}' | awk '/^Timestamp/{t=$0; next} ; /^size/ && $2 != last_size { print t ; print ; last_size = $2 }' | tail"`. On the CLI it works perfect. Any idea why?

Comment: @dotancohen, Don't use aliases, use functions. It doesn't work above because the $2, $0 are inside double quotes so get expanded by the shell. Run `alias` alone to see.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it works as a function. Have a peaceful weekend!