# Limit grep context to N characters on line

Tags: grep, search

I have to grep through some JSON files in which the line lengths exceed a few thousand characters. **How can I limit grep to display context up to N characters to the left and right of the match?** Any tool other than grep would be fine as well, so long as it available in common Linux packages.

This would be example output, for the **imaginary grep switch Ф**:

```
$ grep -r foo *
hello.txt: Once upon a time a big foo came out of the woods.

$ grep -Ф 10 -r foo *
hello.txt: ime a big foo came of t
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101701/grep-characters-before-and-after-match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display lines 2-4 after each grep result?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/how-to-display-lines-2-4-after-each-grep-result)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is about ± characters but your suggested alternative is about ± lines. (Your reference to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101701/grep-characters-before-and-after-match) is good, though.)

Comment: You never use `grep` on JSON documents, you use a JSON parser such as `jq`. I assume that the lines are long because the JSON format does not require newlines between values or keys.  Parsing out a key's value would presumably be what you want to do, which is the most basic operation a JSON processor can do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With GNU `grep`:

```
N=10; grep -roP ".{0,$N}foo.{0,$N}" .
```

**Explanation:**

- `-o` => Print only what you matched
- `-P` => Use Perl-style regular expressions
- The regex says match 0 to `$N` characters followed by `foo` followed by 0 to `$N` characters.

If you don't have GNU `grep`:

```
find . -type f -exec \
    perl -nle '
        BEGIN{$N=10}
        print if s/^.*?(.{0,$N}foo.{0,$N}).*?$/$ARGV:$1/
    ' {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

Since we can no longer rely on `grep` being GNU `grep`, we make use of `find` to search for files recursively (the `-r` action of GNU `grep`). For each file found, we execute the Perl snippet.

Perl switches:

- `-n` Read the file line by line
- `-l` Remove the newline at the end of each line and put it back when printing
- `-e` Treat the following string as code

The Perl snippet is doing essentially the same thing as `grep`. It starts by setting a variable `$N` to the number of context characters you want. The `BEGIN{}` means this is executed only once at the start of execution not once for every line in every file.

The statement executed for each line is to print the line if the regex substitution works.

The regex:

- Match any old thing lazily<sup>1</sup> at the start of line (`^.*?`) followed by `.{0,$N}` as in the `grep` case, followed by `foo`followed by another `.{0,$N}` and finally match any old thing lazily till the end of line (`.*?$`).
- We substitute this with `$ARGV:$1`. `$ARGV` is a magical variable that holds the name of the current file being read. `$1` is what the parens matched: the context in this case.
- The lazy matches at either end are required because a greedy match would eat all characters before `foo` without failing to match (since `.{0,$N}` is allowed to match zero times).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>That is, prefer not to match anything unless this would cause the overall match to fail. In short, match as few characters as possible.</sub>

Comment: Very nice, thank you. This has the drawback of highlighting the entire output, not just the searched for text, but that can be worked around by appending `| grep foo` to the end (however loosing the filename highlighting in the process).

Comment: @dotancohen I guess you can't win them all :)

Comment: w/ GNU `grep` you can specify match colors/applications based on flags applied via environment variables. so maybe even you *could* win em all, *(no promises - not even sure it would work in this case)* but i dont personally see the relevance here... anyway... keep playing.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a note, using `zsh` I am unable to get it to work passing N=10 as in the example. However it does work if I `export N=10` prior to running the command. Any idea how to adjust the example to work with zsh?

Comment: Or `perl -lne 'print "$ARGV: $_" for /.{0,10}foo.{0,10}/g'`

Answer (score 57):

Try to use this one:

```
grep -r -E -o ".{0,10}wantedText.{0,10}" *
```

**-E** tells, that you want to use extended regex

**-o** tells, that you want to print only the match

**-r** grep is looking for result recursively in the folder

**REGEX:**

*{0,10}* tells, how many arbitrary characters you want to print

**.** represents an arbitrary character (a character itself wasn't important here, just their number)

**Edit:** Oh, I see, that Joseph recommends almost the same solution as I do :D

Comment: Thank you. Even though it is essentially the same solution, it is confidence-inspiring that this is the best method when _two_ people independently recommend it.

Comment: You're welcome, Unix community simply must cooperate, that's what we are :-)

Comment: Although they are similar the accepted answer didn't work for me (still produced long lines), but one this did.  The trick with N=10 doesn't work with a bash shell.

Comment: in **cygwin** `-E` is significantly faster than `-P`.

Comment: this suggestion works on Mac, the suggestion from Joseph R. unfortunately doesn't, although they are pretty close to each other

Answer (score 52):

**Piping stdout to `cut` with the `-b` flag; you can instruct grep's output to only bytes 1 through 400 per line.**

```
grep "foobar" * | cut -b 1-400
```

Comment: So much better than all that regex nonsense!

Comment: This only gives the first 400 bytes of the matching line. It does not give N bytes before and after the match. Even worse, suppose 'foobar' appears after the 400th byte, then you wouldn't even see the match in the output!

Comment: @joseph yes but the only reason I use this command to limit the output of grep, is because sometimes a match is found half way through a 5 gigabyte json file where everything is on a single line, and so grep returns 5000 pages of stdout which is useless to me.  I'd rather only see the first 400 bytes, if the highlight isn't there, I know this from a massive file, and most times it's not what I want anyway.

Comment: doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This is computationally WAY faster than using a modified regex as in the accepted answer -- in my tests, about 10-20X faster than a regex matching 10 chars on either side, and 130–360X faster than a regex matching 255 chars on either side! 255 chars is the maximum number one can match for a single character on some systems, but cut allows more context to be preserved (except for very long lines where cut may truncate away the part with the match). This solution is therefore far more practical in many use cases involving large datasets.

Comment: @DavidArndt Discovers that ansi C is between 5 to 15 orders of magnitude faster than newer fashionable programming languages. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4YRPdRXKFs

Answer (score 6):

Taken from: http://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/08/18/truncate-long-matching-lines-of-grep-a-solution-that-preserves-color/
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029954/1150462

The suggested approach `".{0,10}<original pattern>.{0,10}"` is perfectly good except for that the highlighting color is often messed up. I've created a script with a similar output but the color is also preserved:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
#   grepl PATTERN [FILE]

# how many characters around the searching keyword should be shown?
context_length=10

# What is the length of the control character for the color before and after the matching string?
# This is mostly determined by the environmental variable GREP_COLORS.
control_length_before=$(($(echo a | grep --color=always a | cut -d a -f '1' | wc -c)-1))
control_length_after=$(($(echo a | grep --color=always a | cut -d a -f '2' | wc -c)-1))

grep -E --color=always "$1" $2 | grep --color=none -oE ".{0,$(($control_length_before + $context_length))}$1.{0,$(($control_length_after + $context_length))}"
```

Assuming the script is saved as `grepl`, then `grepl pattern file_with_long_lines` should display the matching lines but with only 10 characters around the matching string.